# send jquery var to php in my code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**.js code is loaded on index.php load. I want to send [date var] to php**

```
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    numberOfWeek: 0,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            var date = year +'-'+month;
            var newDate =  new Date(year, month, 1)
            $(this).datepicker('setDate',newDate);
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't know where to place it. So I didin't.

Comment: Have you attempted any ajax? it looks like you have the value, check out https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place whatever you want to send in reqObject. You can access this object in you php code as the requestBody.

Call back is the function you want to execute after you get response from the server.

url is noting but the url to which you are posting your data

```
var reqObject = {"newDate":newDate}  
var type = 'POST'
var url = "your post url"
var callback = function(data){
  console.log(data)
  //Your code goes here   
}  
sendData(type,reqObject,url,callBack);


    sendData: function(type,reqObject,url,callBack) {
        $.ajax({
            type: type,
            data: reqObject ,
            dataType: "json",
            url: url ,
            success: function(response){
               callBack(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: @RUJordan explanation addeed. :) Now you can do a +2 :)